# Spree - Creating site-wide preferences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

This is probably a routine job for anyone who customizes Spree to fit their needs, but I'm having quite a hard time with it.

I want to create a preference that will store an array of products, in order to display them as "featured products" in the homepage. I went through [this guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/preferences.html), and I already created a file under **lib/spree/** in my application tree. The file looks like this:

```
class Spree::HomepageConfiguration < Spree::Preferences::Configuration
  preference :featured_products, :string
end
```

After that I added the lib/spree folder in the autoload_paths in the **application.rb** file:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/spree/)
```

Finally I created an initializer called **homepage_configuration** under **config/initializers/** to configure the preference:

```
module Spree
  Spree::MyApp::Config = Spree::HomepageConfiguration.new
end

Spree::MyApp::Config[:featured_products] = ["a", "b"]
```

But, when I run the server I get this error:

```
Expected C:/path/to/my/application/lib/spree/homepage_configuration.rb to define HomepageConfiguration (LoadError)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions are welcome.

I'm running Rails **3.2.13** and using Spree from **1-3-stable** branch.

Answer (score 1):

Even is an really old question... I've been asked before for this same issue (configuring site wide spree preferences) recently.

As for the error reported and the code supplied, the **lib/spree/homepage_configuration.rb** should be:

```
module Spree
    class HomepageConfiguration < Spree::Preferences::Configuration
      preference :featured_products, :string
    end
end
```

Here is a sample gist with a configuration example I give recently https://gist.github.com/mumoc/55dce225244fb02363e2

Comment: I followed your steps as written down in the github gist.

Does this also immediatly create a settings route/page? If so, where can i access this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it a property of the product? Doing it your way would require a server restart and change of code every time you want to change a product.

I just added a checkbox to the product description to check when the product would be featured, and added a scope to the model `scope :featured, lambda { |*args| { :conditions => { :featured => true }, :limit => args.first || 6, :order => "RAND()" } }` that way you can check and uncheck at will.